# Give out custom tokens for free

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I want to write a smart contract to create the token. 
When I will get a new user in my system, I want to give out tokens for that user for free. New user could appear on any day.
Is it possible or should I always pay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to send tokens:

1) If user sends ETH to your smart-contract, he will automatically get tokens (according to smart-contract code). User pays for transaction.

2) You generate ETH/BTC/any_altcoin address for user. User sends amount of altcoins and gets phantom tokens, which you store in database. Over time you need to send tokens to each user manually or with script (if we talk about erc20 - users should provide their ETH address). You pay for transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

Assuming you are talking about an ERC20 token, you can write a program that triggers a `transfer` function each time a new user comes on your platform.